# Perl HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath duplicate record in next iteration

Tags: perl, xpath

I have created an object using the
[`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) module
and am using it to parse the contents of two webpages.

Page 1: Data parsed and printed as below

```
alaska/fairbanks
```

Page 2: Data parsed and printed as below

```
alaska/fairbanks
alazka/arizona
```

The data from first iteration is also getting into second one.
Please help to avoid this.

Comment: We can't help unless we see your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` object for each web page